# Eliminate duplicate file names in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am stuck in XSLT program, which eliminates the duplicates in output. Help appreciated

XML input:

```
<changelog> 
<entry>     
    <file>
        <name>web/JavaSource/oig/asoig/web/resource/AsoigResources.properties</name>
        <revision>1.7.2.6</revision>
        <prevrevision>1.7.2.5</prevrevision>
    </file>     
</entry>
<entry>     
    <file>
        <name>AdminEJB/ejbModule/oig/admin/dao/schema/TableCode.java</name>
        <revision>1.1.4.2</revision>
        <prevrevision>1.1.4.1</prevrevision>
    </file>
    <file>
        <name>web/JavaSource/oig/asoig/web/resource/AsoigResources.properties</name>
        <revision>1.7.2.6</revision>
        <prevrevision>1.7.2.5</prevrevision>
    </file>     
</entry>    
</changelog>
```

Desired output:

```
web/JavaSource/oig/asoig/web/resource/AsoigResources.properties
AdminEJB/ejbModule/oig/admin/dao/schema/TableCode.java
```

Note: AsoigResources.properties is duplicate in input XML.

XSLT Code used:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry/file">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>        
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I need XSLT to remove the duplicates. I tried using "following-sibling", but didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following XPath expression for your `xsl:for-each`:

```
entry/file[not(name = preceding::name)]
```

Select files whose name does not match any preceding name.

Answer (score 4):

XPath (and, by extension XSLT) 2.0 includes a `distinct-values()` function which will do exactly what you need. Additionally, it makes your `<xsl:for-each/>` expression unnecessary.

```
<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(entry/file/name)" />
```

Comment: Even in XSLT 1.0, many processors support the [EXSLT set:distinct() function](http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another XSLT 1.0 alternative that uses a **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)** and the **[Muenchen method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="fileByName" match="file" use="name"/>

    <xsl:template match="changelog">
      <xsl:for-each select="entry/file[generate-id() =
                                       generate-id(key('fileByName', name)[1])]">
           <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>        
           </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```